# How do I integrate Couchbase mobile into my Android Phonegap project

Tags: android, cordova, couchbase

Back story --

My app requires a database of users. I would like to store the user database on Cloudant, and store an individual user in a local database on the app so they can update their details when offline. The two databases should sync at various times. I think Couchbase Mobile has the power to do this.

Actual problem --

Following the install instructions [here](https://github.com/couchbase/Android-Couchbase), I get stuck when modifying the main activity ('Starting Couchbase' onwards), at this point I think the instructions should differ as I am using Phonegap. I am not too Java savvy, could anybody help?

Kind Regards
Danny

Answer (score 2):

Couchbase Mobile has been superseded by [TouchDB](http://touchdb.org/), though because Phonegap operates in JavaScript, I recommend using [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/) as it's built for that environment. To install PouchDB in your project, just include it like any JavaScript file:

```
<script src="path/to/pouchdb.js"></script>
```

Then, to connect PouchDB to your Cloudant database, execute this in your JavaScript:

```
var pouchdb = Pouch('https://[username]:[password]@[username].cloudant.com/[database]')
```

Though, that exposes your password in your frontend, which you should never do. Instead, look into [per-user security with CouchDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055450/couchdb-authorization-on-a-per-database-basis).

Hope that helps!

Comment: My goodness! I didn't see your reply for 7 years. Thank you, though.